# Prefix with TikZexternalize does not work for me

Tags: tikz-external

The example bellow comes from the [documentation of TikZ](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) (p610).
It does not work my computer. Note that it works when I comment the option `[prefix=figures/]`.
Any idea of what could go wrong here?

```
\documentclass{article}
% main document, called main.tex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/] % activate

\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{trees}
\begin{tikzpicture} % will be written to ’figures/trees.pdf’
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzsetnextfilename{simple}
A simple image is \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt);. % will be written to ’figures/simple.pdf’
\begin{tikzpicture} % will be written to ’figures/main-figure0.pdf’
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a directory named `figures` in your working directory? I just added this directory to my code sandbox and it worked!

Comment: Oh! The shame is on me! It was so simple! Thanks

Comment: If all would be that easy ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I created an answer from your comment, in order to tick the question  as answered (in two days). But of course, if you add yourself the answer I will choose yours!

Comment: No, that's ok... It will give you a self-learner badge then :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Christian Hupfer:
The directory named `figure` must already exist in the working directory. That's all!